# How to override angular2 templateUrl request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have one angular aplication that request your pages to server as that:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'city-form-edit',
 templateUrl: '/view/city/form', //-> Request to Asp.Net MVC server
 styleUrls: ['city.css'],
})
```

Im using JWT (json web token) to authenticate in my application and all it's working nice, but the angular request to get page is without the JWT header and because this, the server returns 401 unauthorized.

My question is, what is the best way to workaround this, if is possible ...

The only idea that i have is override XMLHttpRequest and put the token on header.

Comment: If you don't need authentication, you can set an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the controller method that returns you the view.

Comment: I know, but i need authentication...

Comment: So there is no other way than adding the token to the request.